# Merge objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this, and I want to merge the objects, if the consecutive states are the same.

InputArray

```
[ {"state" : "A", "st" : 12, "et" : 14 },
  {"state" : "A", "st" : 14, "et" : 16 },
  {"state" : "B", "st" : 20, "et" : 94 },
  {"state" : "B", "st" : 94, "et" : 104 }
]
```

Expected output (here `st` will be first Object consecutive object and `et` will be last consecutive object):

```
[ {"state" : "A", "st" : 12, "et" : 16 },
  {"state" : "B", "st" : 20, "et" : 104 }
]
```

Comment: Are they always consecutives? Did you try anything?

Comment: May or may not be consecutives

Comment: Do you need to do this in python?

Comment: What language is this? Please add a tag. Also, what does this have to do with [JSON](http://json.org), which is a string-based format for exchanging information, often with a server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But if you try to achieve this on javascript just try this Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7dsychcx/)

```
function remove_duplicates(objectsArray) {
    var usedObjects = [];

    for (var i=objectsArray.length - 1;i>=0;i--) {
        var newRecord = true;
        for (var j=usedObjects.length - 1;j>=0;j--) {
             if (usedObjects[j].state == objectsArray[i].state) {
                    newRecord = false;
                break;
             }         
        }
        if (newRecord) {
            usedObjects.push(objectsArray[i]);   
        }
    }

    return usedObjects;

}

var objectsArray = [{"state" : "A", "st" : 12, "et" : 14 },
  {"state" : "A", "st" : 14, "et" : 16 },
  {"state" : "B", "st" : 20, "et" : 94 },
  {"state" : "B", "st" : 94, "et" : 104 }];
var clean = remove_duplicates(objectsArray);

console.log(clean);
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by state, then turn each group into an object with the desired fields:

```
function merge(input) {
  const groups = groupBy(input, function(elt) { return elt.state; });

  const states = Object.keys(groups);
  const result = [];

  for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    const group = groups[state];
    result.push({
      state: group[0].state,
      st: group[0].st,
      et: group[group.length - 1].et
    });
  }

  return result;
}
```

Writing `groupBy` is left as an exercise. Or, you could use Underscore's `_.groupBy`. It takes an array, and a function specifying the criteria for grouping, and returns an object whose keys are the group name and values are an array of all the elements falling into that group.

The code above then loops through each property in the groups object, and for each, pushes onto an array of results a single object taking the `st` from the first member of the group and the `et` from the last.

If you are using Underscore, you could simplify things by using its `_.map` on objects:

```
function merge(input) {
  return _.map(_.groupBy(input, 'state'), (key, items) => ({
    state: key,
    st: items[0].st,
    et: items[items.length - 1].et
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this at place;

```js
var arr = [ {"state" : "A", "st" : 12, "et" : 14 },
            {"state" : "A", "st" : 14, "et" : 16 },
            {"state" : "B", "st" : 20, "et" : 94 },
            {"state" : "B", "st" : 94, "et" : 104 },
            {"state" : "C", "st" : 37, "et" : 42 }
          ],
reduced = arr.reduceRight((p,c,i,a) => { p.state == c.state ? (p.st = c.st, a.splice(i,1))
                                                            : p = c;
                                         return p;
                                       });
console.log(arr);
```